# Before drilling a well, how can I determine any water table impact?

Tags: water, water-management, construction, planning

I own a property that has no water service and thus I need to drill a well.  My neighbors have expressed concern about the water table being lowered by too many people with wells in the area.

Before I drill the well, what steps, if any, can I take to reduce the impact my new will will have on the existing water table?  Does drilling deeper have any benefit to the water table or does that just allow mine to function longer than other wells that might not be so deep?

Comment: Are your neighbours' concerns to be taken seriously? What arguments are they based on?
Have they found out that the water source (aquifer) is not being replenished?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally speaking, any water consumption will lower the water table. But if *the [aquifer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquifer) is being steadily replenished* and *less water is drained from the area*, then the only concern is the current depth of existing wells. Some might need to be drilled deeper, if the water level drops. Then the total water table lowering might be bigger than expected.

There are several counter-measures you can take to lower the impact of a new well:

1. Possible ways to help replenishing the water source:

   - cleaning/regulating a nearby stream, river or spring
   - recycling the precipitation locally (underground reservoirs, retention ponds)
2. Ways to lower draining water from the area:

   - enough vegetation (keeps water, prevents too much evaporation)
   - less concrete, asphalt & unpermeable surfaces (quick water drain off)
   - recycling the precipitation locally